# Foreach Loop - Display items differently, first 3 item, items 4-6 etc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops, foreach

Im hoping this will be an easy one..

I have a list of items in my MVC view, for the first 3 I want to display the items inside  then for items 6-10, inside .

Example below:

```
 @foreach (var Article in @Model.ContentList)
 {

 // for Items 1 - 3
<h1>@Article.Title</h1>


 // for Items 4 - 7
<h2>@Article.Title</h2>

 // for Items 7 +
<h3>@Article.Title</h3>

}
```

Whats the best way of doing this inside my view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a for loop instead of foreach.

```
@for ( int i = 0; i < Model.ContentList.Count; i++ )
{
   var Article = Model.ContentList[i];
   if ( i < 3 ){
      // for Items 1 - 3
      <h1>@Article.Title</h1>
   } else if ( i < 7 ){
      // for Items 4 - 7
      <h2>@Article.Title</h2>
   } else {
      // for Items 7 +
      <h3>@Article.Title</h3>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think a better answer would be to re-design your `model`.

`Article` class should contain in itself what sort of header it has, for example...

```
public class Article
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }  // for example
}
```

then within your view

```
@foreach (var Article in @Model.ContentList)
{

     if(Article.Type == "Big")
     {
         <h1>@Article.Title</h1>
     }
     else if(Article.Type == "Medium")
     {
         <h2>@Article.Title</h2>
     }
     else if(Article.Type == "Small")
     {
         <h3>@Article.Title</h3>
     }
}
```

Comment: +1.  This is the only (current) answer that avoids arbitrary numbers and defines something more concrete.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Thanks, yes I try to avoid logic like others have suggested within my views. just feels dirty.

Comment: Thanks Moo-Juice, I see what your saying..do the logic in the controller. Mzetko has provided what I was after, but food for thought.

Comment: @Dez79 just so you know, it was me that answered the question :)

Comment: Apologies squirrel - Brain Fog Monday - Thanks!